# on mouse click span element not set focus

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I had attached some keyboard navigation on span all keyboard keys are working find up, down, left, right. but when setting the focus on mouse click it's not working I had also tried to `setTimeout` before set focus but that did not work in my case.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".navigate").click(function() {
    $(this).focus();
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: burlywood;
}

.navigate {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 96px;
  height: 96px;
  margin: 2px;
  background-color: brown;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.foucs {
  border: 1px solid #fff !important;
}

.row {
  background-color: violet;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <div class="row">
    <span class="navigate" tabindex="1">1</span>
    <span class="navigate" tabindex="1">2</span>
    <span class="navigate" tabindex="1">3</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span class="navigate" tabindex="1">4</span>
    <span class="navigate" tabindex="1">5</span>
    <span class="navigate" tabindex="1">6</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span class="navigate" tabindex="1">7</span>
    <span class="navigate" tabindex="1">8</span>
    <span class="navigate" tabindex="1">9</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your CSS to this...

```
.navigate:focus {
  border: 1px solid #fff !important;
}
```

Instead of...

```
.foucs {
  border: 1px solid #fff !important;
}
```